# Редактирование ячеек TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Всем привет. Использую `TableView` на форме OS X. Связываю колонки таблицы с массивом. Кнопочки на форме создают и удаляют строки из таблицы - все работает. Но почему то не могу редактировать содержимое ячеек в таблице TableView ни кодом, ни с клавиатуры в рантайм? Содержимое ячек таблицы постоянно "Table View CELL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос снят, по умолчанию TableView содержит TableCellView, его нужно удалить